# HTML5 speech recognition callbacks are ignored

Tags: speech-recognition

I am trying to embed speech recognition API, but the below code fails. Control doesn't go inside function(event). Can someone help and Suggest.

```
function startDictation() {

  if (window.hasOwnProperty('webkitSpeechRecognition')) {

  var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();

  recognition.continuous = false;
  recognition.interimResults = false;

  recognition.lang = "en-US";
  recognition.start();

  recognition.onresult = function(event) {

        document.getElementById('transcript').value  = event.results[0][0].transcript;
        console.log(event);
        recognition.stop();
        document.getElementById('saurabh').submit();
     };

     recognition.onerror = function(event) {
        console.log("Hello");
        console.log(recognition.onerror);
        recognition.stop();
     }

  }
}
```

Comment: please share html code as well to debug easily

Answer (score 0):

You need to set callbacks first, then call `recognition.start()`. In your case you start recognition without setting callbacks.